# Generate Edi 276 file

Tags: c#, edi

I am trying to generate an Edi 276 file by code. Can I create this file from xml or can I write a txt file with the edi format and than save as edi?

Comment: An EDI file *is* a text file, so yes, you can write a text file with the EDI format and save that as edi.

Comment: ok thanks....Also can you please explain how we can reverse it i mean how to read edi in c#.Like i will get response in EDI 277.So how i parse the response.....

Comment: No, I cannot, EDI is a pain of a format, you need a custom parser, not because it is a text file or hard to grok how the fields are split, but you need something that understands EDI 277 so that you don't have to write that yourself. That is why I left a comment on the *text* part of the format, I specifically avoided the format itself :)

Comment: You can try out [EDI.Net](https://github.com/indice-co/EDI.Net) in order to do the parsing and saving. The EDI 276 is based on X12 so it will be fairly straightforward. *disclaimer: I am the author of the library*